# Data loss occurred while upgrade nopCommerce database 2.3.to 3.0

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nopcommerce

I have been worked in the nopCommerce 2.30 in the past one year. Last month I have decided to upgrade the nopCommerce version 2.3 to 3.0. I searched the web to get helpful links for the upgrade process. I had concentrate on the DB side upgrading.

But I found some strange things mainly in the Customer table. After execute the upgrade script in the database just run the SELECT Query in the Customer table. There is major difference found in the Customer table rows count, before upgrading the Database the Customer rows is greater than 8000 rows but now the rows count is 5000. I just run the upgrade scripts only.

(Running the upgrade script respectively 2.4, 2.5, 2.6... 3.00).

I am clueless what happened to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any DELETE FROM [Customer] statements  in any of the upgrade scripts between 2.3 and 3.1.  Maybe your Delete Guests task ran for the first time after the upgrade?  The only way to be sure what you lost is to load up your DB backup and compare the records.